# Advance bit manipulation, leaving empty bits in any pos

Tags: c++

I have two chars, `a` and `b`. I am trying to store a `15 bit int` in those chars, but I must leave the 8th bit of the first char **untouched**.

I know how to do this without the gap on the 8th char:

```
unsigned int num = 32767;
unsigned char a = num;
unsigned char b = (num & 0xFF00) >> 8;

cout << "The num is: " << (unsigned int)a + ((unsigned int)b << 8);
```

Can someone please help me understand how this works, so I can learn to leave any bit or bits empty in any position?

Comment: Despite your way of displaying the results, the core question is actually not C++ related. If I was you, I would replace the cout's by printf's and tag this as C.

Comment: @Till: Huh? C++ is quite capable of bit manipulation.

Comment: @DavidHammen Hehe, yes - I was actually recommending that as the question in its core is bit manipulation using C syntax. That is certainly fully C++ compatible. Its mostly for making sure that the audience is widened as any C++ coder knows that C syntax is usable but not any C coder will check C++ related questions/answers.

Comment: @Luka: What do you mean by "the eighth bit of the first char" -- Do you mean the most significant bit or the least significant bit?

Comment: I learned to love [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) class from [tag:c++] to overcome kind of such situations.

Comment: @David Hammen: I don't care, either is fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming by "eighth bit", you mean the most significant bit... Try:

```
unsigned int num = 32767;
unsigned char a = 0, b = 0;

a &= 0x80;                               // Preserve only the MSB of a
a |= (num & ((1 << 7) - 1));             // Bit-wise OR the seven LSBs of num
b  = (num & (((1 << 8) - 1) << 7)) >> 7; // Set b equal to the remaining eight bits of num.

cout << "The num is: " << (unsigned int)(a & 0x7F) + ((unsigned int)b << 7);
```

Here's the key... If you want to make a bit mask that's m bits long starting n bits from the right, you can use this expression:

```
mask = ((1 << m) - 1) << n;
```

Then, you can just use the & operator to set every bit not in the mask to 0, >> to shift the result, and = or |= to set the bits appropriately.

**Alternative**

Here's an alternative solution in case you meant least-significant bit instead of most-significant bit:

```
unsigned int num = 32767;
unsigned char a = 0, b = 0;

a &= 0x01;                               // Preserve only the MSB of a
a |= (num & ((1 << 7) - 1)) << 1;             // Bit-wise OR the seven LSBs of num
b  = (num & (((1 << 8) - 1) << 7)) >> 7; // Set b equal to the remaining eight bits of num.

cout << "The num is: " << (unsigned int)((a & 0xFE) + ((unsigned int)b << 7);
```

Comment: Please explain what are you doing there

Comment: @Luka Explanation added... Let me know if you have specific questions about any particular step.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I run this I get: 32895

Comment: Note: This interprets the "eighth bit" as meaning the MSB of `a`. I would interpret it the other way around, as the LSB. It's ambiguous. It was your response that made me ask Luka to clarify the intention of the question.

Comment: Please give me a little time to test it, but seems ok

Comment: @DavidHammen Added the solution for LSB for completeness.

Comment: OK, it works! Can I ask you please to tell me how to store a 14 bit int and leave the last bit of `a` and the last bit of `b` empty?

Comment: @Luka Four changes... Add `b &= 0x80;`, change `b = ...` to `b |= ...`, change `(1 << 8)` to `(1 << 7)`, and change `b` to `(b & 0x7F)` in your `cout` statement.

Comment: @Luka _'how to store a 14 bit int'_ That's the reason why I'd prefer using [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) to solve such a problem, I could put the numeric range in question as a simple template parameter.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: in my case speed is pretty important

Comment: @Luka **Why** do you think, usage of a `std::bitset` for finding a solution would affect performance of the resulting code, can you elaborate on that? IMHO it will result for pretty much the same whilst having better readability, of what's done behind the scenes, and the code is produced at compile time (or are you trying enhance compilation performance??).

Comment: While you are correct, in some cases you can't sacrifice even 5% of performance for readability. I can't believe the std class does this without 5-10% performance hit compared to the best c++ code. I care about execution performance.

Comment: @Luka My point is, if you're going to use a `std::bitset<7>` or a `std::bitset<14>` variable, to prevent touching the _'1st'_ bit, the code reproduced from this class with all the remaining necessary operations won't show worse performance than this answer actually does (IMHO at the end it should render up pretty much the same code). As long I don't see proving anyone the opposite, I'll stick to it (the existing implementations of `std::bitset` I've been using so far are pretty efficient, as far I can tell!).

Comment: I will keep this in mind an I may run some tests. Thank for pointing it out.